# Display text in the closest element with certain class

Tags: javascript, function, foreach, closest, queryselector

I'm trying to display a text in the closest element with the .msg class, but it always displayed in the first element with .msg class.

```js
let btn = document.querySelectorAll('button');

btn.forEach(function(i) {
  i.addEventListener('click', function() {

    let x = document.querySelector('.msg').innerHTML = i.innerHTML;
    let z = x.closest(".msg");

  });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="btn">button 1</button>
  <p class="msg"></p>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="btn">button 2</button>
  <p class="msg"></p>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="btn">button 3</button>
  <p class="msg"></p>
</div>
```

[image]

If I click Button1, the text should be displayed underneath Button1, if I click Button2 text should be displayed underneath Button2, and so on...

Comment: [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) finds the closest *ancestor* to the current element. You want [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling), or use `closest` to go to the parent `div` and find the `.msg` within.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

> The closest() method of the Element interface traverses the element and its parents (heading toward the document root) until it finds a node that matches the specified CSS selector.

The `.msg` element is next to the `button` not on of its parents, so you can get the parent element of the button which is the `div`, and then use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) into it to get the `.msg` element.

```js
let btn = document.querySelectorAll('button');

btn.forEach(function(i) {
  i.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const parentDiv = i.parentElement;
    parentDiv.querySelector('.msg').innerHTML = i.innerHTML;

  });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="btn">button 1</button>
  <p class="msg"></p>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="btn">button 2</button>
  <p class="msg"></p>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="btn">button 3</button>
  <p class="msg"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<script>
    let btn = document.querySelectorAll('button')

    btn.forEach(function (i, index) {
        i.addEventListener('click', function () {
            document.querySelectorAll('.msg')[index].innerHTML = i.innerHTML
        })
    })
</script>
```